# thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, Implement three stack in a single array

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

The purpose of this code is to implement three stacks in a single array. I use linked node to implement stack. the elements are pushed into array one by one directly, and the elements in each stack are connected by previous pointer. the pointer is int value corresponding to index in array where the item is stored. `nextAvaIndex`method return next available index that can store new pushed item. Because there will space released in the beginning of the array after executing `pop` method. if`indexused < arr.length`it will keep moving forward to store new item, while if `indexused`reaches end of array, the method will search is there free space in beginning of array.
But when I run it, it throws `NullPointerException`, i know the meaning of this error, but I can't fix it. Thanks for your comments! Is the code correct? One more question of removal an item from int type array. I let`arr[i].data = 0` to delete the item, and use statement `arr[i].data == 0` to check if one space is null. But what if one space store`0`? Thanks for your suggestion!

```
public class FlexiblemultiStack {
```

```
private int[] toppoint = {-1, -1, -1};// assume number of stack ==3;
private int indexused = 0;
private stackNode[] arr;


public FlexiblemultiStack(int sizeEach, int stackNO) {

    arr = new stackNode[sizeEach * stackNO]; //

}

public boolean isEmpty(int stackNum) {
    return toppoint[stackNum] == 0;
}

public void push(int item, int stackNum) {
    int lastIndex = toppoint[stackNum];
    int nextIndex = nextAvaIndex();
    if (nextIndex == -1) {       // if nextIndex = -1, there is no more space!
        System.out.println("There is no more space!");
    } else {
        toppoint[stackNum] = nextIndex;
        arr[toppoint[stackNum]] = new stackNode(item, lastIndex);
        indexused++;
    }
}

public int pop(int stackNum) {
    if (toppoint[stackNum] == -1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int value = arr[toppoint[stackNum]].data;
        int lastIndex = toppoint[stackNum];
        toppoint[stackNum] = arr[toppoint[stackNum]].previous;
        arr[lastIndex] = null;
        indexused--; 
        return value;
    }
}

public int peek(int stackNum) {
    return arr[toppoint[stackNum]].data;
}

public int nextAvaIndex() {
    int index = -1;
    if (indexused == arr.length || arr[indexused].data != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].data == 0) {   // error
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;

    } else {
        return indexused;
    }
}

public void print(int stackNum) {
    while (toppoint[stackNum] != -1) {
        System.out.print(arr[toppoint[stackNum]].data + "<--");
        toppoint[stackNum] = arr[toppoint[stackNum]].previous;
    }
}
public void printarr(){
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
}
public class stackNode {  // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

List item

`private int previous;
    private int data;

    public stackNode(int StackSize) {
        this.previous = -1;

    }

    public stackNode(int value, int prev) {
        data = value;
        previous = prev;
    }
}`

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stackandqueue.FlexiblemultiStack$stackNode.access$000(FlexiblemultiStack.java:86)
    at stackandqueue.FlexiblemultiStack.nextAvaIndex(FlexiblemultiStack.java:61)
    at stackandqueue.FlexiblemultiStack.push(FlexiblemultiStack.java:32)
    at stackandqueue.StackandQueue.main(StackandQueue.java:71)
/Users/xchen011/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: how about letting us see the stacktrace so that we know where the NPE is thrown from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pop()` method, it appears you are denoting an open index by setting the array index to null (`arr[lastIndex] = null`). In `nextAvaIndex()` you check if the index is available by examining `arr[i].data`. If `arr[i]` has been set to `null` by `pop()`, you will get the `NullPointerException`. To make the definition of available consistent with the check for availability, try replacing `arr[indexused].data != 0` with `arr[indexused] != null` and `if(arr[i].data == 0)` with `if(arr[i] == null)` in the `nextAvaIndex()` method.

```
public int nextAvaIndex() {
    int index = -1;
    if (indexused == arr.length || arr[indexused] != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == null) {   // error
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;

    } else {
        return indexused;
    }
```

}